# GeoDjango on Windows: "Could not find the GDAL library" / "OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I've been trying to setup my windows computer such that I can have a local postgreSQL with PostGIS extension. With this installed I hope to be able to create a project with geodjango locally before putting it in the cloud. I have been working with Django for a little while now on my local machine with the SQLite DB, but since the next project will partly be based on coordinate based data I wanted to setup the right environment.

**Import note: I've installed mini-conda to run in a seperate environment. I do activate this environment "development" when I work though**

I've tried to follow most of the geodjango information/tutorials online, but can't get it to work. What I've done (mostly followed this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows):

1. Download and install the latest (10.3) PostgreSQL setup from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads
2. After installation I also installed used the Application Stack Builder to install PostGis
3. I've installed OSGeo4W from https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/
4. I've created a batch script as described on the geodjango website (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows) and ran it as administrator (except for the part where it sets the path to python, cause python was already in there since I've been using python for a while now)
5. I've tried some command in psql shell and I think I've created a database with name: geodjango, username: **** and pass: ****.
6. I don't know if I have given the geodjango user all priveleges, but I suspect so.

After all of this I created a new django project and in settings.py I've added some parts:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.gis',
'nameOfMyApp',
]
```

I've also got this in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': 'geodjango',
    'USER': '****',
    'PASSWORD': '****',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
}
}

# FOR GEODJANGO
POSTGIS_VERSION = (2, 4, 3)
```

When I try to set up the database in django I run (in the right folder):

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal202", "gdal201", "gdal20", "gdal111", "gdal110", "gdal19"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

I've tried to fix that, but nothing seems to work.
Can anybody give me some help in setting this all up locally?

Update 7-3-2018:

- I've tried installing GDAL manually myself, (from: http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1911-x64-gdal-2-2-3-mapserver-7-0-7.zip the generic core components)
- I've installed (what I assume are) the python bindings from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. Still I get the same error.
- I've also tried setting the GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH to the GDAL directory or the gdal-data directory (which resides in the GDAL directory).

Now I get the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

(while the .dll is there...)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I have found the following to work for windows:

- Run `python` to check if your **python** is 32 or 64 bit.
- Install corresponding [OSGeo4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) (32 or 64 bit) into `C:\OSGeo4W` or `C:\OSGeo4W64`:

  - **Note:** Select Express Web-GIS Install and click next.
  - In the ‘Select Packages’ list, ensure that GDAL is selected; MapServer and Apache are also enabled by default, may be unchecked safely.
- Make sure the following is included in your `settings.py`:

  ```
  import os
  if os.name == 'nt':
      import platform
      OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
      if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
          OSGEO4W += "64"
      assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
      os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
      os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
      os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
      os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']
  ```
- Run `python manage.py check` to verify geodjango is working correctly.

Comment: Udi, you are the hero of the day. It seems to work now , thank you!

Comment: Udi you saved me from madness

Comment: It worked, but would be also important to say that the code must be placed at the beginning of the `settings.py` file.

Comment: I am getting this error message 

 File "C:\Users\HP\django_project3\django_project3\settings.py", line 22, in <module>
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
AssertionError: Directory does not exist: C:\OSGeo4W64

Comment: I had installed the 32 bit version by mistake.

Comment: giving this error;  the procedure entry point sqlite2_column_origin_name could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal301.dll

Comment: Tried this but does not seem to work. I still get the same issue, see question asked on GIS Stack exchange https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407905/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-could-not-find-the-gdal-library-t

Comment: @RossSymonds I am also facing the same error. can you help me to install the 64 bit version? btw have you managed to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 34):

After updating some OSGEO4W on my Windows 10 Pro machine I started having problems with the GDAL bindings again. I previously used a combination of the solutions posted here and with [this tutorial](https://www.pointsnorthgis.ca/blog/geodjango-gdal-setup-windows-10/).

This is what works for me using Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, Django 3.0.6 and GDAL 3.0.4 using a python 3.7 virtual environment. I have tested it without OSGEO4W and it seems to work.

First, download the GDAL wheel from [Christoph Gohlke's Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal).

```
pip install "/path/to/GDAL‑3.0.4‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl"
```

Modify the **libgdal.py** file in the virtual envrironment site packages by adding 'gdal300' to line 23 of the Django GDAL package python file (/path/to/virtual_env/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py):

```
elif os.name == 'nt':
    # Windows NT shared libraries
    lib_names = ['gdal300', 'gdal204', 'gdal203', 'gdal202', 'gdal201', 'gdal20']
```

Finally, in your **settings.py** file in your Django project add

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    VENV_BASE = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
    os.environ['PATH'] = os.path.join(VENV_BASE, 'Lib\\site-packages\\osgeo') + ';' + os.environ['PATH']
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = os.path.join(VENV_BASE, 'Lib\\site-packages\\osgeo\\data\\proj') + ';' + os.environ['PATH']
```

Comment: You are the best, finally something works for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: short note: for python 3.8 add `gdal301` as the lib_names.

Comment: And for Python 3.9, install `GDAL‑3.2.1‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl` from the binaries site and add `gdal302` to the `lib_names` list.

Comment: Adding 'gdal301' to the lib_names in libgdal.py solved my problem.

Comment: I am getting KeyError: 'VIRTUAL_ENV' this error how can i get rid off from this i am following your tutorial. I have also posted this error as separate question on stackoverflow.

Comment: After following the instructions in the answer above I was getting the error "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal303", "gdal302", "gdal301", "gdal300", "gdal204", "gdal203", "gdal202", "gdal201", "gdal20"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings." and it turns out my library was named "gdal304" and once I added it to libgdal.py it started working.  Thank you!

Comment: October 2023, this is still the best solution.

I'm using python 3.10 and Django 4.2.6, I downloaded `GDAL-3.4.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl`, and I did not have to change anything in `site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py`. I just tweaked `settings.py` as shown, and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

In my case *(Windows10Pro+Python3.7.1)*, having the (automatically chosen) dll present was not enough, namely `gdal111.dll`.

I realized that I also had `gdal204.dll` located at `C:\OSGeo4W\bin` and tried to "enrich" the list variable named `lib_names` with `'gdal204'`, at line 24 (regarding Windows NT shared libraries) of `%PYTHON_ROOT%\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py`, i.e.

```
#[...]
elif os.name == 'nt':
    # Windows NT shared libraries
    lib_names = ['gdal204', 'gdal202', 'gdal201', 'gdal20', 'gdal111', 'gdal110', 'gdal19']
#[...]            ^^^^^^^
```

No negative consequences for now.

Comment: I was about to say that. This could be a very small improvement in the Python binding, is there a way to add a suggestion / commit to this somewhere?

Comment: @OlivierPons you can [request this improvement on the ticket tracker](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/bugs-and-features/). But I think that it will naturally be integrated in future versions of Django, sooner or later.

Answer (score 3):

For Microsoft Windows 10 & Python3.6.8, I installed GDAL 2.3.3 from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), modified libgdal.py adding `gdal203` in the lib_names list `env\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py`.

Finally, added osgeo and proj to the PATH, and set the GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH as below (beginning of settings.py):

```
os.environ['PATH'] = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, r'env\Lib\site-packages\osgeo') + ';' + os.environ['PATH']

os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, r'env3\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\data\proj') + ';' + os.environ['PATH']

GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, r'env\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal203.dll')
```

In this case, env is my Python environment.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow:

1. Run python to check if your python is 32 or 64 bit.
2. Install corresponding OSGeo4W (32 or 64 bit) into `C:\OSGeo4W` or `C:\OSGeo4W64`:
   Note: Select Express Web-GIS Install and click next.
3. In the ‘Select Packages’ list, ensure that GDAL is selected; MapServer and Apache are also enabled by default.
4. Make sure the following is included in your `settings.py`:

```py
import os
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal300'
```

5. Now, run the server still if it doesn't work. Run the following commands in terminal.

```
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
set PYTHON_ROOT=C:\Python3X 
set GDAL_DATA=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\gdal 
set PROJ_LIB=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\proj
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error "The specified module could not be found," even though `gdal204.dll` was present at the expected location, with the right architecture (which I verified by adding asserts in the Python code and loading the DLL from a C program).

It turned out to be an issue with the [Python 3.7 app from the Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/python-37/9nj46sx7x90p), the one that automatically installs the first time you type `python` on the command line.
This version of Python refuses to load the GDAL DLL; I don't know if it's a bug or a security feature.

I fixed the issue by:

- uninstalling the Python app
- removing the app execution aliases (as explained in [the app description](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/python-37/9nj46sx7x90p))
- installing the regular Python package from [python.org](https://www.python.org/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Download GDAL wheel file that is supported for your platform from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal).
2. Open the command window where the downloaded file is located and activate your virtual environment.

[image: Activating your virtual environment]

3. Then install the wheel using command `pip install name_of_the_file` .

[image: Screenshot 2]

You will see **osgeo** folder has been created in the location **'...\Envs\my_django\Lib\site-packages\'** .

4. Go to **osgeo** folder and copy the entire path of your **gdalxxx.dll** file and add to setting.py file as gdal library path. For example

   `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal300.dll'`

Answer (score 1):

**Creating the map compatible database**

I recently got a new laptop and had to install Python and the related software on my new machine. I was trying to create a geodjango compatible database using OSGeo4W and had forgotten about the role of PostgreSQL and pgAdmin4.

When you install the latest PostgreSQL setup from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads, you get pgAdmin4 at the same time.

Note - Ecommerce is my personal server group.

[image]

When you create a PostgreSQL 13 server, your server group will be different to mine.
[image]

When I first opened pgAdmin4 on my new machine, I kept the default username 'postgres'. If when you first logged into pgAdmin4 you chose your own username, you will have to change the values below accordingly.
[image]

**Connecting to the database**

In my code I had

```
if os.name == 'nt':
import platform
OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
    OSGEO4W += "64"
assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal300.dll'
```

I was getting an error message regarding the GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH so checked Windows Explorer. On discovering I did not have a gdal300.dll file, I changed my code to

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal301.dll'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on the nice and detailed answer of Udi (cannot comment directly as my rep is under 50, it is the answer marked as the most useful);

After many hours I tried his offered solution which also did not work for me.
I was getting the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

But I stayed there and found out that although I'm running 64 python and operating system (for sure), it kept looking for 32 bit (`OSGeo4W`) folder. What eventually let me pass was to copy contents of the `OSGeo4W64` folder to the `OSGeo4W`. Hope it will save you time.

One more note:

Be sure that you edit `libgdal.py` file in your environment folder. It may exist in more than one place - your python folder and environment folder - if you edit the `libgdal` in your python dir, it is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install GDAL
```

(From [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/))

Add In `%PYTHON_ROOT%\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py`

```
import osgeo
```

Check Gdal Vesion In: `%PYTHON_ROOT%\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal303.dll`

```
lib_names = ['gdal303', 'gdal202', 'gdal201', 'gdal20', 'gdal111', 'gdal110', 'gdal19']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to this gdal problem in Django: https://www.dark-hamster.com/application/how-to-solve-error-message-could-not-find-the-gdal-library-when-running-django-application-in-microsoft-windows/?utm_source=pocket_saves.

1. First of all ensure that you have downloaded the OSGeo4W package from [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/). Install it to your computer. It will take quite some time since the full package is >1GB.
2. Ensure that you have a folder `C:\OSGeo4W` in your C Drive.
3. Go to `C:\OSGeo4W\bin` and check for a file such as `gdal306.dll`. In my case I have `gdal306.dll` and `gdal307.dll`. I went with the former.
4. Go to your `settings.py` file in your Django project.
5. If you pasted your Django error somewhere, it read something like this:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal202", "gdal201", "gdal20", "gdal111", "gdal110", "gdal19"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

We will give it a taste of its own medicine by creating a variable `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH` in your `settings.py` file.

6. Copy the path to your `gdal306.dll` file from OSGeo4W folder. In my case it was, `C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal306.dll`. Paste it as the path to the `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH` like so:

`GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal306.dll'`

Note - make sure to add r'absolute_path' instead of 'absolute_path' otherwise this error will come - FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\OSGeo4in\gdal307.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

7. Run your django project once more, if all is ok, there shouldn't be that error again.