# geodjango error importing LayerMapping

Tags: python, django, gdal, geodjango

Setup:

```
Windows 10

Python 2.7

Django 1.11

Standalone GDAL install gdal-202-1911-core.msi from gisinternals

QGIS version 3

PostgreSQL 9.5 with Postgis 2.3
```

[image: Environmental Variables]

**ERROR**

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils import LayerMapping
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name LayerMapping
```

I can open up the layermapping.py, the file is there. There needs to be something wrong with my setup here. what should I be doing to correctly import LayerMapping, why is this happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your geos/GDAL installation is probably broken.  Follow the instructions [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49159195/57952) for properly installing geodjango on windows.