# Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal202", "gdal201", "gdal20", "gdal111", "gdal110", "gdal19")

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, geodjango

I am working on a django project, trying to use GeoDjango.

In my setting.py, I added `'django.contrib.gis',`to installed app but getting this error.

```
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.admin.options import GeoModelAdmin, OSMGeoAdmin
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\options.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.admin.widgets import OpenLayersWidget
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\widgets.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 43, in <module>
    % '", "'.join(lib_names)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal202", "gdal201", "gdal20", "gdal111", "gdal110", "gdal19"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

I have no idea what the error is all about. Could anyone help me out.

Comment: Well the error explains itself clearly: it looks like you did not install the GDAL system on your machine: https://www.gdal.org/

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I installed the GDAL as per this tutorial - https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows

Comment: I am using virtual environment, does I need to set thing for that ?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49159195/57952

Answer (score 11):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs

On Debian/Ubuntu, you are advised to install the following packages which will install, directly or by dependency, the required geospatial libraries:

```
$ sudo apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin
```

Answer (score 1):

install the below library

```
apt-get -y update && \
apt-get -y install \
python-gdal \
python-geoip \
rpl
```

Answer (score 0):

python version 2.7

```
pip install django

pip install psycopg2

pip install pyproj
```

found the gdal wheel here https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal

```
pip install \gdal wheel
```

add 2 system environment variables "GDAL_DATA" and "GDAL_LIB".

```
GDAL_DATA = C:\python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\data\gdal

GDAL_LIB = C:\python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo
```

Then add %GDAL_DATA% and %GDAL_LIB% to your system PATH

go open %PYTHONPATH%\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\ libgdal.py and add str('gdal202') to line 26.

```
lib_names = [str('gdal201'), str('gdal202'), str('gdal111'), str('gdal110'), str('gdal19')]
```