# How to specify GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in Django settings.py?

Tags: gdal, geodjango

I am trying to use GeoDjango for storing GIS data points in PostGIS. I followed windows installation instruction provided in the documentation:-

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows

I followed the answer provided at following the link:-

[GeoDjango on Windows: "Could not find the GDAL library" / "OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139044/geodjango-on-windows-could-not-find-the-gdal-library-oserror-winerror-12?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, after following it, I am getting the following error after running `python manage.py check`:-

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x04588DB0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 101, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 305, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .features import DatabaseFeatures
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\features.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\base\features.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\functions.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .fields import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\fields.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .collections import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\collections.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import GEOSGeometry, LinearGeometryMixin
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\geometry.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import gdal
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Desktop\me\TSL\env-tsl\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 47, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "c:\users\vineet\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

In `settings.py`

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    import platform

    OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W64" # name of the folder
    if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
        OSGEO4W += "64"
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
    os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
    os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']

...


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'rest_framework',
]

...
```

Comment: Are you using 64 or 32 bit python? Please provide a complete traceback

Comment: I am using 64 bit python